# 802.1q tagging on ubuntu 18

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, network-manager

I recently setup an ubuntu server (gui installed) so i've been using

netplan with the following config:

```
network:
        version: 2
        renderer: NetworkManager
```

which means networkmanager is doing all of the configuration.

So I'm assuming I do all of the vlan configuration under network manager (correct me if i'm wrong)

my goal is to have the physical server itself sit on 1 vlan (vlan 10)

and create lxd containers (vlan 20) and vm's that sit on another vlan (vlan 30)

what's the best way to configure this? what are good references? all google is pointing me to are posts that are many years old and for older versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Create connection profiles in NetworkManager to your liking.

For that, use nm-connection-editor, nmtui, or nmcli, whatever suits you best.

See manual pages `nmcli-examples`, `nmcli`,  and `nm-settings`.

Try

```
$ nmcli

$ nmcli device

$ nmcli connection
```

to get an overview.

Finally, something to the amount of

```
$ nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname eth0 ...
$ nmcli connection add type vlan parent eth0 id 1 ...
```